# Formatting print function with list comprehensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, printing

I am trying to write a code where it formats the list comprehension function `[print('{:<15} ${:<4f}'.format(Timeframes[counter],x)) for counter,x in enumerate(Compounding)]` so that it will print the expected output. I am trying to print the values of `Compounding` and `Non_Compounding` on the same row but the `Print Function` that i am trying to do does not work. How would I be able to run it like the Expected Output?

Code:

```
import numpy as np

Timeframes = ['Last Month:', 'Three Months:', 'Six Months:', 'Last Year:', 'Last Two Years:', 'Entirety:']
Compounding = np.array([97.44704833566995, 77.20626280482892, 232.04635122144302, 424.5742707027069, 4076.195731389482, 28513.877490504994])
NonCompounding = np.array([98.7019108522086, 79.00055035682558, 198.89764228943147, 268.25878090471525, 514.6930939260048, 938.811329948405])

print("\t\tCompounding ")
[print('{:<15} ${:<4f}'.format(Timeframes[counter],x)) for counter,x in enumerate(Compounding)]
print("\n\t\tNon Compounding: ")
[print('{:<15} ${:<4f}'.format(Timeframes[counter],x)) for counter,x in enumerate(NonCompounding)]
```

Print Function:

```
[print('{:<15} ${:<4f}\t\t${:<4f}'.format(Timeframes[counter],x,y)) for counter,x,y in enumerate(Compounding,NonCompounding)]
```

Output

```
                Compounding 
Last Month:     $97.447048
Three Months:   $77.206263
Six Months:     $232.046351
Last Year:      $424.574271
Last Two Years: $4076.195731
Entirety:       $28513.877491

                Non Compounding: 
Last Month:     $98.701911
Three Months:   $79.000550
Six Months:     $198.897642
Last Year:      $268.258781
Last Two Years: $514.693094
Entirety:       $938.811330
```

Expected Output:

```
                Compounding        Non Compounding
Last Month:     $97.447048         $98.701911
Three Months:   $77.206263         $79.000550
Six Months:     $232.046351        $198.897642
Last Year:      $424.574271        $268.258781
Last Two Years: $4076.195731       $514.693094
Entirety:       $28513.877491      $938.811330
```

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension for looping, use ordinary `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip()` to loop over the lists in parallel.

```
for timeframe, compound, noncompound in zip(TimeFrames, Compounding, NonCompounding):
    print(f'{timeframe:<15} ${compound{:<4f} ${noncompund:<4f}')
```

There's no need for a list comprehension. `print()` doesn't return anything, so you're just creating a list full of `None`. And you're not assigning the resulting list anywhere.